# Most efficient way to add titles to elements with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, title, object-literal

I have some French numbers up to 24 as text in paragraph elements (some occurring more than once) on a page and I want to go through them and add the relevant English translation as a title attribute. I've got a solution, but I don't think it's the most efficient, so I'm just looking for a bit of help to write something neater, if possible, and was interested in your solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a translations object where the `key` is the number in French and the `value` is the English translation.

```
var translations = {
    "un" : "one",
    "deux" : "two",
    ...
};
$('.demonstration [class*="col"] p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('title', translations[$this.text().replace(/\s+/g, '')]);
});
```

Comment: How about when the number isn't in the list? My answer uses `|| null` to cover this.

Comment: @alijsh If the number isn't in the list then attempting to access it will return `undefined`, and no title attribute will be set.

Answer (score 1):

Use Arrays and Objects instead:

```
var myTitles = { vingtquatre : 'twenty four', vingtdeux: 'twenty two' }; // add your other keys and values here in that same format, no matter what the order is inside.

$(this).attr('title', myTitles[$(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a list:

```
var nums = { 'un': 'one', 'deux': 'two', ... }
```

And then, replace `switch` with this:

```
$(this).attr('title', nums[$(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, '')] || null);
```

note that `|| null` is for when the number isn't the list i.e. it acts like the `default` part of the `switch`